# Prevent NG0100 ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when programmatically switch tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on an Angular app using Angular Material Design components (version 15.1.1 for both). I've run into a situation that results in an `NG0100 ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error showing in the console, and I haven't been able to eliminate it with any of the typical approaches.

The scenario is this: I have 2 tabs implemented using `mat-tab-group`. The first tab has a `matInput` field with `matAutocomplete` attached; this is used to search and select a complex object. The second tab has form fields that show the details of the complex object. When the user selects an autocomplete item, the controller populates the form fields on the second tab with data from the selected object and programmatically switches to the second tab. It is the programmatic switch to the second tab that causes the error.

I've created a simple app that reproduces the error here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyq59p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html

The HTML for the input+autoselect looks like this:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select 1, 2, or 3</mat-label>
  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    [formControl]="myControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  />
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
      [value]="option"
    >
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

The controller code that handles the selection looks like this (see stackblitz for the full code):

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.myControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(filter((value) => typeof value == 'object'))
    .subscribe((value) => this.setSelectedValue(value as TestData));
}

private setSelectedValue(value: TestData) {
  this.selectedValue = value;
  this.myControl.setValue('');
  this.tabIndex = 1;
}
```

If you run the stackblitz and look at the error message, you'll see that it mentions `mat-form-field-hide-placeholder` as the value that changes. It appears that the cause of the error is the form field on the first tab losing focus, which causes it to change how the label is displayed. I've also noticed that the error doesn't happen on FireFox, and it appears that the search input doesn't lose focus when switching tabs on FireFox.

I've tried all the standard approaches to solve this, including manually running change detection and putting `setTimeout` around various parts of the code. So far the only thing that has worked is putting an `*ngIf` around the input field so that it is removed from DOM when the first tab isn't selected. While this eliminates the error in the console, it introduces some UI behavior changes that I'd like to avoid.

Any other ideas on how to eliminate the NG0100 error?

Follow-up question: while I generally try to eliminate these errors during development, in this case it seems very unlikely to cause any UI instability because it affects a control that isn't visible. What are the risks of leaving it as-is?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this seems to be related to the order of the dom elements being updated, with the visibility change applied to the elements inside the first tab then the entire tab hidden.

I tried switching to lazy-loading your tabs content, and it seems to solve your issue:

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading

```
<mat-tab label="Look Up">
      <ng-template matTabContent>
            <mat-form-field>...
      </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="Show Me">
      <ng-template matTabContent>
            <div class="show">You Selected {{selectedValue?.name}}</div>
      </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyq59p-p8ostu?file=src/app/autocomplete-filter-example.html

Comment: This does eliminate the error but has the same UI behavior change problems as `*ngIf`.